# SSAS Cube Edit-named-query has different value than in EXCEL

Tags: excel, ssas

Here is what I have setup. We have a SQL Database and a Table lets call this Database MW and the table is Cust table. and I have an SSAS cube that uses MW as data source.

In my CUBE , If I select the datatable CUST and select EDIT named query
add where clause and click the green play button in visual studio . I get the value of Quantity = 100.30

[image]

But when I have excel pivot table connected to the SSAS Cube, I get a different value (say the quantity is 100.00) .

100.30 is the correct value. I intentionally change some values in my CUST table . RUN the SSAS cube process and to see if it will update in the excel (connected to the ssacs CUBE). but it seems to be not updating.

I deploy and process the SSAS multiple times. I can see that if I change the formatstring of a Facts , it shows up in EXCEL. so I know it is updating something. but I don't know why the value is not syncing.

This is my SSAS Cube process

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Parallel>
    <Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400" xmlns:ddl500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500" xmlns:ddl500_500="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2013/engine/500/500">
      <Object>
        <DatabaseID>MW</DatabaseID>
      </Object>
      <Type>ProcessFull</Type>
      <WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
    </Process>
  </Parallel>
</Batch>
```

Probably missing some details for you to help me. but it is a simple straight forward one table, one cube setup. no complex setup as far as I can tell.

any speculation What could be the problem? thanks